# Sitecore crashing application pool when using Security Editor on a specific role

Tags: iis, iis-6, sitecore, sitecore6

Starting today, whenever I try and use security editor on either of two similar roles I get a timeout. If I try again IIS reaches an error threshold of some kind and stops that Application Pool. Then all of our users receive a "Service Unavailable" message from IIS.

I can edit other roles. This error can be recreated.

I assume I have some kind of database corruption, but I can't find an error that helps me in Event Viewer or the Sitecore logs. Where else can I look for more detail?

IIS6, Windows Server 2003, Sitecore 6.2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds to me like you've got a circular reference in your roles.

Are you using the default role provider, ASP.NET membership?  If so, try using the default Microsoft security tools (you can get at 'em via Visual Studio).  If that doesn't work, you can programmatically modify these roles using the API.

Also, I believe there is a known issue which may be fixed in a 6.2.x update.  I would check the change list at SDN.  Here: http://sdn.sitecore.net/Products/Sitecore%20V5/Sitecore%20CMS%206/ReleaseNotes/ChangeLog.aspx

Yep... take a look at the 6.2.0 rev 100701 update list.